# Plotting graphs with glVertex2i() shows artefacts when scaled with glScaled()

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

I'm using OpenGL to plot an RGB image histogram. As this is an 8-bit image histogram, my data-set contains data points from zero to 255.

If I plot the histogram without using glScaled() then the graph plots as expected but, of course, does not fill the allocated area (the width of which is variable, the height constant). However, when I use glScaled() the graph shows strange artefacts.

Please see the following images to see an example of the problem:

[image: Histogram without glScale]

*The image above shows the histogram as plotted with 256 data points without being scaled with glScaled().*

[image: Histogram plot with glScale]

[image: Same as above but with a larger scale]

*The two images above shows the histogram as plotted with 256 data points AND being scaled with glScaled(). The strange artefacts are evident (missing data?). Please note, the third histogram is a slightly different shape due to changing light levels.*

Here is the relevant part of my OpenGL initialisation code:

```
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(0.0f, width, height, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

// If this line is removed then the graph plots correctly
// m_scale_factor = width / 256
glScaled(m_scale_factor, 1.0, 1.0);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

And here is the relevant part of my plot code:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);

glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for (int n = 0; n < m_histogram_X; n++)
{
    glColor4ub(255, 0, 0, 255);
    glVertex2i(n, m_Hist_Channel_R[n]);
    glVertex2i(n, GRAPH_HEIGHT);

    glColor4ub(0, 255, 0, 255);
    glVertex2i(n, m_Hist_Channel_G[n]);
    glVertex2i(n, GRAPH_HEIGHT);

    glColor4ub(0, 0, 255, 255);
    glVertex2i(n, m_Hist_Channel_B[n]);
    glVertex2i(n, GRAPH_HEIGHT);
}
glEnd()

...
```

At this stage I feel that I must state that I am new to OpenGL, so it's possible that I have misunderstood many OpenGL things...

My question is: Is it possible to fix this problem in OpenGL or will I have to increase the number of data points by some kind of interpolation and then plot without scaling?

I appreciate any help offered.

Comment: If you're new to OpenGL I suggest you learn modern OpenGL. What you're learning is 10+ year deprecated OpenGL. See https://learnopengl.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split the rendering into 3 passes, you should be able to use triangle strips instead of line strips (which should fill in the gaps).

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glColor4ub(255, 0, 0, 255);
for (int n = 0; n < m_histogram_X; n++)
{
    glVertex2i(n, m_Hist_Channel_R[n]);
    glVertex2i(n, GRAPH_HEIGHT);
}
glEnd()

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glColor4ub(0, 255, 0, 255);
for (int n = 0; n < m_histogram_X; n++)
{
    glVertex2i(n, m_Hist_Channel_G[n]);
    glVertex2i(n, GRAPH_HEIGHT);
}
glEnd()

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glColor4ub(0, 0, 255, 255);
for (int n = 0; n < m_histogram_X; n++)
{
    glVertex2i(n, m_Hist_Channel_B[n]);
    glVertex2i(n, GRAPH_HEIGHT);
}
glEnd()
```

Comment: That has solved the problem for 8-bit image histograms and 16-bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no data missing. It's just, that you're using a drawing primitive in a way that doesn't suit the data. GL_LINE_STRIP draws one long continuous line, connecting the dots as you pass them in, and also interpolating between the colors you set.

Essentially what you do is, draw a line blue-to-red from the last blue bin to the next red bin height, then from the red bin to the green bin and from there to the blue bin. And then you skip over to the next red bin and so on. So essentially you're drawing small "spikes" with connecting lines between red and blue. Of course there will be gaps if there are more pixels in width to fill, than there are bins.

I suggest you take a piece of (graphing) paper and carry out the drawing steps yourself, by hand, to understand how this outcome happens.

Truth to be told: This is not the most efficient way to draw a histogram anyway. A much better approach is to load the histogram data into a 1D texture, draw one large quad (or better yet a viewport filling triangle, using scissor testing to cut the viewport to a rect) and for each fragment (roughly that's a pixel, with some extra stuff) in *the fragment shader* use the X coordinate to look up the bin from the texture and subtract the Y coordinate from the texture and pass the result into the `step` or `smoothstep` GLSL function to determine the color for the pixel. As strange it might sound to a newbie, but drawing a single triangle and doing the rest in the fragment shader *is* more efficient, that submitting a swath of polygons. It also gives much better quality!

#### Update – example shader

A practical application might be implemented with a shader like this (Shadertoy semantics):

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    // read the histogram data from a sampler
    // on shadertoy there are no 1D textures, so we use a
    // single row of a 2D texture instead, and sweep up/down
    // over time to get a "dynamic" histogram.
    vec3 h = texture(iChannel0, vec2(uv.x, sin(0.01*iTime))).rgb;

    // discard fragments which are "outside" the histogram
    // also use this value later for the alpha channel
    float a = smoothstep( 0.000, 0.001, length(h));
    if( 0. == a ){ discard; }

    // Color the fragment. The smoothstep gives some antialiasing.
    // For perfect pixel coverage based antialiasing we'd have to
    // determine the slope of the histogram, to construct a tangent
    // and determine the distance to it, i.e. create a
    // Signed Distance Field
    fragColor = vec4(
        smoothstep(-0.001, 0.001, h.r - uv.y),
        smoothstep(-0.001, 0.001, h.g - uv.y),
        smoothstep(-0.001, 0.001, h.b - uv.y),
        a );

    // Instead of using the smoothstep and/or the SDF using a
    // multisampled buffer and performing a simple `y >= h` test
    // would yield probably a nicer result.
}
```

The result then looks like this

[image: Shader based histogram]

Comment: Simply plotting the three colors separately, to avoid the color changes between adjacent vertexes, would go a long way toward fixing the problem.

Comment: @datenwolf Thanks for your helpful comment. As I said, I am very new to OpenGL and what you suggest sounds relatively complicated to my newbie GL status. I would need to invest more time in learning OpenGL and, unfortunately, time is the essence.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I tried your suggestion and it did make things much better but, alas, still not perfect. I think, at least for now, I will interpolate extra data points and plot without glScaled(). Once I have the time, I can learn more about OpenGL and implement a solution similar to that described by datenwolf

Comment: @Amanda: I've updated my answer with some shader code. You'll still need some OpenGL host code to load the shader and the histogram into the texture. But this should give you the idea.

Comment: @datenwolf Many thanks for this, it's appreciated. I will experiment with your idea.